# Uninitialized constant Spell_check::Mashape (NameError) when using Mashape spell chech API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to use the Mashape Spellcheck API https://www.mashape.com/montanaflynn/spellcheck. The way I did it is I created a class that gets initiated every time I want to use the spellcheck API. And every time I initiate it and call a method I wrote in that class - I get this error message 
`check_spell.rb:19:in 'run_script': uninitialized constant Spell_check::Mashape (NameError)`
What am I doing wrong?

The executable file looks like this: testSpel

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require_relative './lib/check_url'
require_relative './lib/extract_tags'
require_relative './lib/check_spell'

def instruction 
<<EOS

# Enter the url/file to be checked
# Enter 'Q' or 'q' to exit 
# Enter 'Help' for usage information

EOS
end

def menu 
 puts instruction
 url = gets.chomp
 controller(url)
end

def controller(url)
  if url == "q" || url == "Q" 
   puts "Bye!"
  elsif url == ""
   puts "Invalid url"
   menu
  else
   check_url(url)
  end 
end

def check_url(url)
  if url.length > 0 
    test_url = Url_check.new(url)
    if test_url.validate == 1
      check_tags = Grab_text.new(url)
      text = check_tags.print_p
      check = Spell_check.new(text)
      check.run_script
    else 
      puts "#{url} is not a valid url. Please enter a valid url"
      puts menu
    end 
  end 
end 

menu
```

lib/check_spell.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'unirest'
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'uri'

class Spell_check

  def initialize(sentence)
    @sentence = sentence
  end 

  def run_script
    response = Unirest.get "https://montanaflynn-spellcheck.p.mashape.com/check/?text=This+sentnce+has+some+probblems.", headers:{:X-Mashape-Key => "yPE6iL0onCmshTi11F0PM89eYtjGp1xxxeBjsnppk45Zxxx"}
    puts response
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you edit your question removing your X-Mashape-Key from the code as this can be used against you.
Secondly, because Spell_check lives in another module you are required to use the full name notation when invoking it.

Hope this helps,

best